# LINQ to XML - how do I obtain index

Tags: c#, linq, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, indexing

I have an array of Car objects and using the following piece of code I create an XML Document from these objects. I have set up a counter variable `i` to be able to index the Car elements in the document. Is there a different way of obtaining the index of the currently processed element?

```
        int i = 0;
        XDocument doc =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement(
                    "Inventory",
                    from car in cars
                    select
                        new XElement("Car",
                            new XAttribute("ID", ++i), //<<== index here
                            new XElement("Color", car.Color),
                            new XElement("Make", car.Make),
                            new XElement("PetName", car.PetName)
                        )
                )
            );
```

The approach I have taken works fine, I am just wondering whether there's a magic word or extension method that will yield the index without my incrementing a counter variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup - don't use a query expression; use the [overload of `Select` which provides an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx). This replaces your query expression:

```
cars.Select((car, index) =>
    new XElement("Car",
        new XAttribute("ID", index),
        new XElement("Color", car.Color),
        new XElement("Make", car.Make),
        new XElement("PetName", car.PetName)
    ))
```

There are various overloads which aren't supported in query expressions - it's definitely worth being familiar with both "dot notation" (or whatever you want to call it) and query expressions.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [overload of Select which takes an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) so you can change your query expression to this:

```
cars.Select((c, i) => new XElement("Car", new XAttribute("ID", i) ...))
```